# How to recover MYSQL database, once you have lost the latest frm files but you have latest ib files

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb

I have accidently deleted mysql database from phpmyadmin but when I checked /var/lib/mysql, I could find all the ib* files.

This is a frequent transactional database

I have .sql backup of 2 days ago.

How can I restore?

I tried uploading old backup to create .frm files and copied ib* files , restarted the mysql server but then it starts giving error table doesn't exist.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Maybe you can try this admin/infrastructure question at http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Use the `.sql` file. If you dropped it, it's dropped, new MySQL configurations store all the persistent data in the database directory. The `ib*` files contain mostly uncommitted transactional data and recent log activity, nothing more. Random MySQL internal files are not going to help. You need everything or it's going to be a mess.